# Which of Elasticsearch and Neo4j would be more suitable for this scenario?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, neo4j

Let's consider a dating like app.

Considering that each user has a number of interests, I want to find the users that have common interests with the current user, ordered by the number of common interests.

Which one would be more suitable for this type of query? Elasticsearch, Neo4j or something else? The queries should be as fast as possible so that the user doesn't have to wait for a long time to see his/her potential matches. There can be millions of users. There wouldn’t be deep relationships between people, only between people and interests.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At least my experience with Neo is, that it tends to be slow for text search in bigger databases. And since you do not have deep relationships, i would go with Elasticsearch. Using other databases would depend on what the input/interests looks like. if it is some free written text your good with elasticsearch analyzers. If there are just some categorys i guess a simple sql database could also fit.